# Как ввести данные типа Дата с клавиатуры?

Tags: eclipse, java

Добрый день. Столкнулся с ситуацией - требуется ввести дату с клавиатуры.
Задать дату по умолчанию(программно) разобрался, а с этим трудности. Как ввести дату с клавиатуры? (Eclipse, консольное приложение)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-нибудь в таком духе

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Date date = sdf.parse(br.readLine());
```

Разумеется, придётся в последствии читать только из br, либо получать текст как-то по другому.

Comment: Спасибо, это как раз то что нужно!
Дальше первых двух строк я не продвинулся:)